# When was which ArcGIS Version published?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I need a list of all ArcGIS products and their versions including the date of publication. Most important is the ArcGIS Desktop versions, but others would be interesting, too. I bet it is all somewhere out in the net, but google didn't want to help me this time.

Any sources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at ArcGIS Desktop in Wikipedia it will give you what you want: [ArcGIS Desktop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS). look at the right side of the page there is ArcGIS version history.

```
Version Released
8.0     1999-12-27
8.0.1   2000-01-13
8.1     2001-05-01
8.2     2002-05-10
8.3     2003-02-10
9.0     2004-05-11
9.1     2005-05-25
9.2     2006-11-14
9.3     2008-06-25
9.3.1   2009-04-28
10.0    2010-06-29
10.1    2012-06-11
10.2    2013-07-30
10.2.1  2014-01-07
10.2.2  2014-04-15
10.3    2014-12-10
10.3.1  2015-05-13
10.4    2016-02-18
10.4.1  2016-05-31
10.5    2016-12-15
10.5.1  2017-06-29
10.6    2018-01-17
10.6.1  2018-07-16
```

For [ArcGIS for Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcGIS_Server) it is also showed on Wikipedia but the release dates are different from the ArcGIS Desktop:

```
Version Released
9.0     2004-5-01
9.0.1   2005-1-01
9.1     2005-5-01
9.2     2006-11-0
9.3     2008-6-01
9.3.1   2009-4-01
10.0    2010-6-30
10.1    2012-6-11
10.2    2013-7-30
10.2.1  2014-1-07
10.2.2  2014-4-15
10.3    2014-12-1
10.3.1  2015-5-13
10.4    2016-2-18
```